# create and set ios refresh buttons in titanium

Tags: button, titanium, refresh, appcelerator, simulator

I know how to create and set the iOS refresh buttons in titanium but i do not know how to make them actually refresh data in tabs/windows. I have created refresh buttons for my app.js and four other tabs but it does not refresh data.

```
var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');


var scrollView4 = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
  contentWidth: 'auto',
  contentHeight: 'auto',
  showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
  showHorizontalScrollIndicator: true
});
Titanium.UI.currentWindow.add(scrollView4);
var currentWin4 = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;





var refreshBtn = Titanium.UI.createButton({
     Color: 'black',
     systemButton : Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.REFRESH
});
currentWin4.setLeftNavButton(refreshBtn);
currentWin4.add(refreshBtn);





var l1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  left: 10,
  top: 15,
  width:'auto',
  height:40,
  color: '#1E90FF',
  text: 'About us',
  font: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20
    }
});
scrollView4.add(l1);





var l2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  left:10,
  top: 50,
  width:'auto',
  height:40,
  color: '#336699',
  text: 'photo sharing app',
  font: {
        fontSize: 13
    }
});
scrollView4.add(l2);





var l3 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  left: 10,
  top: 90,
  width:'auto',
  height:40,
  color: '#336699',
  text: '',
  font: {
        fontSize: 13
    }
});
scrollView4.add(l3);









var l5 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  left: 10,
  top: 170,
  width:'auto',
  height:40,
  color: '#336699',
  text: 'locate us!',
  font: {
        fontSize: 13
    }
});
scrollView4.add(l5);





var l6 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  right: 10,
  top: 250,
  width:'auto',
  height:40,
  color: '#1E90FF',
  text: 'Development & API',
  font: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 20
    }
});
scrollView4.add(l6);





var b1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
  right: 10,
  top: 290,
  width:'auto',
  height:40,
  color: '#336699',
  title: 'Development & API',
  font: {
        fontSize: 13
    }
});
scrollView4.add(b1);







var l9 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    center: 0,
    top: 460,
    width: 'auto',
    height: 40,
    color: '#1E90FF',
    text: 'complaints?'
});
scrollView4.add(l9);





var b2 = Ti.UI.createButton({
  center: 0,
  top: 500,
  width:'auto',
  height: 40,
  color: '#336699',
  title: 'talk to us'
});
scrollView4.add(b2);





var emailDialog = Titanium.UI.createEmailDialog({toRecipients:['zyaine@gmail.com']});
        emailDialog.Subject = ('');
        emailDialog.messageBody = '';





b2.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    emailDialog.open();
});





emailDialog.addEventListener('complete',function(e)
{
    if (e.result == emailDialog.SENT)
    {
        alert("message sent");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("message not sent");
    }
```

Comment: Got any code? Unclear what you are asking without it.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have editted my question with a sample code (tab)

Comment: Ok... I didnt mean a code dump, can you trim it down to what you think the problem is?

Comment: there is nothing in your code for refresh Button's listner . What do you mean by refresh ? are you willing to clear fileds data on  click refresh button ? Another thing,you are adding refresh button in left navigation as well as in scrollView. Be  clear what you want to get correct solution ,thanks

Comment: guys pardon me, i dnt have sound knowledge of titanium yet...i have the refresh button but i want, on click, it will refresh the data in the page. If am still not explaining it well, please give me a sample code that i can learn with. Thanks.

Comment: [Set data in a function .On button click you can call that function](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/144320/refresh-tableview-with-a-button)

Comment: [Refresh tableViewdata on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272021/after-refresh-dont-append-the-same-data)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement an event handler

```
 refreshBtn.addEventHandler('click', function(e) {
  //Add code here that will fetch row data and redraw.
 }
```

Without having more info it is tough to answer more specifically

Comment: thank you for your reply, i have editted my question with a sample code (tab)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your code that represents any data that could be refreshed... in general, you need a "click" event handler for the button. 
Inside the click handler, you can for example use the setData() method on a TableView object to set data for the TableView.

Or for a WebView, you could reload it's URL.

If you want to repaint the Window/View I'm afraid there is no dedicated method for that. You could try if applyProperties() causes a repaint. But I'm not sure why one would want to do that in the first place.

It would be helpful if you tell us more about the data you want to refresh. What kind of data, where does it come from etc.